# Is constantly mounting another drive safe?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, hard-drive

Is it safe to constantly mount another drive having another os inside it ?

For example, Windows 10 is on Drive C, while Ubuntu is on drive D. Sometimes, when I'm using Ubuntu (Drive D), I always need some file from Drive C. I do so since 2 months. Now, my pc hdd got corrupted / bad sector, I can't get inside the windows os and ended up losing all my files.

Is this because my pc hdd is old (i used that hdd since 2013), or is it because I am doing it wrong ? I am trying to do the same thing again but I am afraid it  will damage my hdd again.

Here is my disk screenshot where Windows 10 is located
[image]

and here is my disk screenshot where Ubuntu is located
[image]

If anyone is wondering, I am using gnome look for big sur mac os

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please open the Disks app in Ubuntu and take a screenshot by pressing Alt+PrintScreen buttons together. Then upload the screenshot in imagur.com. Finally [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1293701/edit) and add a link to the uploaded screenshot in the question.

Comment: ok, i will try to make my question more clearer, thanks before

Comment: 7 year old hard drive can be expected to go bad, so can one you just brought new.  Mounting should not damaged a drive, Unmounting not safely can(power outage, unplugging from USB during writing).  Ubuntu is reporting both disks OK.  Are you saying that you cannot read your data partition, sdb1?  Should try fixing that partition from Windows, not Ubuntu, since it is NTFS partition.

Answer (score 2):

Mounting drive can't cause any bad sectors. This is a physical problem.

Did you confirm it's "bad sectors" vs just "corrupted data"?